# Why can't I install clamcour?

Tags: 10.10, server, clamav

```
sudo apt-get install clamcour
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando Ã¡rbol de dependencias
Leyendo la informaciÃ³n de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete clamcour
ricardo@laboratorio:~$
```

It says *Can not localize the package clamcour*, I updated the OS, and also uncommented the repositories on sources.list. What can I do to install clamcour on this server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like this should be "Can not *locate* the package" instead of "localize" .

Comment: @user10778  Any particular reason to use clamcour?   You'll have to replace exim with Courier first....

Answer (score 2):

That's beacause it's not in the repositories, you need to build it from source.

[Download it first](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clamcour/)

and then:

[Installation](http://www.becrux.com/index.php?page=projects&name=clamcour):

- · cd build
- · cmake ..
- · make
- · make install
- · type "filterctl start clamcour" ...
  check your mail log for clamcour
  activation.